# R:Keep values in first ROW in r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am quite new with R and this is my first post on this forum.

I have a data frame based on the vlaues from a CSV file in to a dataframe and it looks like:

```
ID name   V1   V2    V3    V4    V5
7  ABC    5    NA    NA    NA    NA
7  ABC    NA   3     NA    NA    NA
7  ABC    NA   NA    6     NA    NA
7  ABC    NA   NA    NA    3     NA
7  ABC    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

This is the output which i am trying to get out from this dataframe:

```
ID name   V1   V2    V3    V4    V5
7  ABC    5    3     6     3     NA
```

Comment: it's not the same question. The answer can be incorrect for this one

Comment: @jyjek The first answer from the duplicated link works for me. `df %>% group_by(ID, name) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))` If this is different question OP needs to clarify it and I would be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @RonakShah Hi. I think `sum`!=last value in this case. Anyway question isn't fully correct

Comment: Maybe this help `df%>%group_by(ID)%>%tidyr::fill_(names(.))%>%dplyr::slice(nrow(.))`